# Meteor - Insert and/ or update entries in database from JSON array

Tags: javascript, json, meteor, underscore.js

I would like to have a JSON File through which i feed my database with new entries. If the entry already exists, it should be checked if the entry is modified. if so, then the entry should be updated. If its new, it should be inserted. 
I managed to insert new entries but for the updating i got stuck and the code won't run:

```
Fruits = new Mongo.Collection('fruits');

var fruitSeeds = [
{
    "nameId": "passionFruit",
    "name": "Passion Fruit",
},
{
    "nameId": "banana",
    "name": "Banana",
},
{
    "nameId": "pineapple",
    "name": "Pineapple",
},
{
    "nameId": "orange",
    "name": "Orange",
}
];


_.each(fruitSeeds, function (fruit) {
    if (fruit.nameId === Fruits.findOne({
            name: fruit.nameId
        }).nameId) {
        Fruits.update(fruit);
        console.log("updated", fruit.name);
    } else {
        Fruits.insert(fruit);
        console.log("inserted", fruit.name);
    };

});
```

Thanks for your help!
Vin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use upserts. See http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/upsert.

Example for your case:

```
_.each(fruitSeeds, function (fruit) {
    Fruits.upsert({nameId: fruit.nameId}, fruit);
});
```

The problem with your implementation is that the update function requires a selector parameter. The first parameter selects which object in the database to update. The second parameter is the modifier.

Thus this would work fine as well:

```
Fruits.update({nameId: fruit.nameId}, fruit);
```

However, I recommend to use upsert in this case. Upsert will create a document in the database if the selector doesn't match any existing documents. If it does, it will update the document.